# How do I sign a sendTransaction with an angular service using ethersjs and metamask

Tags: angular, solidity, metamask

I am using angular 9 and I am getting the following error when I try to run the following code.  How do I sign the transaction?

Error: sending a transaction requires a signer (operation="sendTransaction", version=4.0.47)

```
      onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form);
    this.submitted = true;
    // TODO: This is where we connect to the solidity contract to create client.
    this.clientService.createClient(form.controls['accountAddress'].value, form.controls['name'].value).subscribe(
      (model: Client) =>
      {
        this.model = model;
        console.log('MODEL='+model);
      }, error => {
        console.log("error"+error);
      });
  }



export class ClientServiceService {

  //mweb3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545')); // keeping this for future reference.
  // Attempting to use the example from MI4-exercise7 to use metamask
  provider = new ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider('ropsten')
  contractAddress = "0xe6482f6554074c666593b5f38fe5357828a1fbd7";
  contractABI = [...];

  contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.contractABI, this.provider);

  //constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  constructor() { }

  // getInvoiceTracker(): ethers.Contract {
  //   return this.contract.new();
  // }

  createClient(clientID: string, clientName: string): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.contract.addClient(clientID, clientName));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To send transactions you need to use a provider with a signer.

```
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider)
```

and then connect your contract instance to the signer.

```
contract.connect(wallet)
```

If you're connecting MetaMask then create an ethers provider from the window web3 provider:

```
  provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
```